# SQL Server [PATSTAT] query | Multiple charindex values &

Tags: sql, sql-server, charindex, string-agg

Hello Stack Overflow Community.

I am retrieving data with SQL from PATSTAT (patent data base from the European Patent Office). I have two issues (see below). For your info the PATSAT sql commands are quite limited.

---

### I. Charindex with multiple values

I am looking for specific two specific patent groups ["Y02E" and "Y02C"] and want to retrieve data on these. I have found that using the charindex function **works** if I insert one group;

```
and charindex ('Y02E', cpc_class_symbol) > 0
```

But if I want to use another charindex function the query just **times out**;

```
and charindex ('Y02E', cpc_class_symbol) > 0 or charindex ('Y02C', cpc_class_symbol) >0
```

I am an absolute SQL rookie but would really appreciate your help!

---

### II. List values from column in one cell with comma separation

Essentially I want to apply what I found as the "string_agg"-command, however, it does not work for this database. I have entries with a unique ID, which have multiple patent categories. For example:

```
appln_nr_epodoc | cpc_class_symbol

EP20110185794 | Y02E  10/125

EP20110185794 | Y02E  10/127
```

I would like to have it like this, however:

```
appln_nr_epodoc | cpc_class_symbol

EP20110185794 | Y02E  10/125, Y02E  10/127
```

---

Again, I am very new to sql, so any help is appreciated! Thank you!

I will also attach the full code here for transparency

```
SELECT  a.appln_nr_epodoc, a.appln_nr_original, psn_name, person_ctry_code, person_name, person_address, appln_auth+appln_nr,  
appln_filing_date, cpc_class_symbol
FROM
tls201_appln a
join tls207_pers_appln b on a.appln_id = b.appln_id
join tls206_person c on b.person_id = c.person_id
join tls801_country on c.person_ctry_code= tls801_country.ctry_code
join tls224_appln_cpc on a.appln_id = tls224_appln_cpc.appln_id
WHERE appln_auth = 'EP'
and appln_filing_year between 2005 and 2012
and eu_member = 'Y'
and granted = 'Y'
and psn_sector = 'company'
and charindex ('Y02E', cpc_class_symbol) > 0
```

Comment: for first issue use UNION so Query_1 where charindex ('Y02E', cpc_class_symbol) > 0 Union Query_2 where charindex ('Y02C', cpc_class_symbol) >0

Comment: For 2nd issue looks like you are trying to PIVOT the data. You may have to do some reasearch around this. As PIVOT works best with aggregate and SET NUMBER OF EXPECTED VALUES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your part 2 here is a sample data i created
And here is the code. It gives me YOUR requested output.

```
create table #test_1 (
            appln_nr_epodoc varchar(20) null
            ,cpc_class_symbol varchar(20) null
            )

            insert into #test_1 values
            ('EP20110185794','Y02E  10/125')
            ,('EP20110185794','Y02E  10/127')
            ,('EP20110185795','Y02E  10/130')
            ,('EP20110185796','Y02E  20/140')
            ,('EP20110185796','Y02E  21/142')



            with CTE_1 as (select *
            from (
            select * 
            ,R1_1 =  Rank() over(partition by appln_nr_epodoc order by cpc_class_symbol )
            from #test_1
            ) as a
            where R1_1 = 1
            )

            ,CTE_2 as (select *
            from (
            select * 
            ,R1_1 =  Rank() over(partition by appln_nr_epodoc order by cpc_class_symbol )
            from #test_1
            ) as a
            where R1_1 = 2 ) 

            select a.appln_nr_epodoc
            ,a.cpc_class_symbol+','+c.cpc_class_symbol
            from CTE_1 a
            join CTE_2 c on c.appln_nr_epodoc = a.appln_nr_epodoc
```

Out put [image]